# How to capture non-fish-eye video with wide angle lens?

Tags: camera, video, streaming-video, image

We're using this fisheye lens: [https://www.amazon.com/SainSmart-Fish-Eye-Camera-Raspberry-Arduino/dp/B00N1YJKFS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1511631477&sr=8-1&keywords=raspberry+pi+wide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N1YJKFS)

When we preview the camera with PiCamera, the default resolution is 1920x1080 and there is no fisheye effect. We need to reduce the resolution to 368x207 (which is the same 16:9 aspect ratio). To do that we did

`camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (368,207)
camera.start_preview()`

For some reason, after we reduce the resolution we see a very strong fish eye effect which isn't there at the full resolution. Alternatively, we can capture the image at full resolution and reduce the size using PIL. This however results in sub-optimal performance.

**How do we reduce the image size to 368x207 in picamera without getting a fisheye effect?**

Comment: Have a look at [sensor modes](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html#sensor-modes) in the picamera docs. At 1080p the heuristic is selecting a sensor mode with partial FoV. At 368x207 it's probably using a full FoV mode. You can force the sensor mode on construction with the [`sensor_mode` parameter](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/api_camera.html#picamera.PiCamera.sensor_mode)

Comment: @DaveJones perfect that worked. would mark as accepted if you make that an answer.